# Conditionally Formatting Specific Cells (heatmap style) based on a corresponding range or criteria

Tags: excel, vba, heatmap, conditional-formatting

I have a range of values that represent different outcomes. Within that range there is a value ( one per row) that I am trying to target to apply the color-shading (heat map; gradient RBY) to. The criteria is $I4+0.5=BJ$3:BP$3. Again, there can and will only be 1 match.

I've tried so many different scenarios via Chat GPT and have had zero luck.

The image below is the outcome of me manually clicking the cells and applying the heat map. That is the end goal of what I want, but obviously there is a ton of data, that changes each day that I don't want to be doing manually.

Additionally, I've added a helper column/range ( =$I4#+0.5=BQ$3:BW$3 ) where "TRUE" is the match to the criteria. Not sure if it is needed, but that was one of the scenarios I tried working through. I'm at a loss here. Any help is more than appreciated.

[image]

This was the code I was working off of, but this didn't target the specific cells as well as it wasn't a conditional format, it was changing the interior colors

This code correctly applies the heatmap color scheme to all of the cells in T4:Z1101

```
    Sub ApplyHeatMapColorScale()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim dataRange As Range
    
        ' Set the worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Analysis")
    
        ' Set the range for your data
        Set dataRange = ws.Range("T4:Z1101")
    
        ' Clear existing formatting
        dataRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Set default color
    
        ' Apply the specified heat map color scale to the data range
        With dataRange.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
            ' Dark Red
            .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(226, 0, 0)
    
            ' Light Yellow
            .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132)
    
            ' Dark Green
            .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        End With
    End Sub
```

This code checks that the TRUE FALSE in the helper range are able to be correctly identified

```
    Sub TestConditionIdentification()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim conditionRange As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim i As Long
    
        ' Set the worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet
    
        ' Set the range for the condition (TRUE/FALSE)
        Set conditionRange = ws.Range("AA4:AG1101")
    
        ' Loop through each cell in the condition range
        For Each cell In conditionRange
            ' Check if the value is TRUE
            If cell.Value = True Then
                ' Display a message box for each TRUE cell
                MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " is TRUE"
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Just having trouble putting the two together some how.

Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

- The helper range is not necessary.
- Two conditional formatting rules are applied on data rage.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyHeatMapColorScale()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim oFC As FormatCondition
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full Analysis")
'    Set ws = Sheet2 ' for testing
    ' Remove existing fc
    With ws.Cells
        For i = .FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
            .FormatConditions(i).Delete
        Next
    End With
    ' Set the range for your data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BJ").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("BJ4:BP" & lastRow)
    ' Apply the specified heat map color scale to the data range
    With dataRange.FormatConditions
        .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT($I4+0.5=BJ$3)"
        .Item(1).StopIfTrue = True
        With .AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=3)
            ' Dark Red
            .ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            .ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(226, 0, 0)
            ' Light Yellow
            .ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            .ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132)
            ' Dark Green
            .ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            .ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [FormatCondition.StopIfTrue property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.stopiftrue?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm512088)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [FormatCondition.SetFirstPriority method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.setfirstpriority?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm512091)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.FormatConditions property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formatconditions?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144226)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]